# angularjs login page with database postgres

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, authentication

I am new to Angularjs and I want to validate the Angularjs login details with postgres database.

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example).

For the login page in this example, local storage has used to save data.

[This example](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-todo) uses todo app with the Postgres database. 
How do I make the first repo login page work with Postgres?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: the question is about mix between first example with th second ...i want to make login page with database